# Pass facebook profilePicture,profileId to profileViewController.

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, protocols, facebook-ios-sdk

I have been able to pass the user.name facebook properties to profileViewController.

But I'm not able to send the FBProfilePicture though here is the method below:

```
// this method will be called when the user information has been fetched
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    FBProfilePicture.profileID = user.id;
    FBNamePass = user.name;
    [self pushViewController:FBNamePass andProfilePicture:FBProfilePicture];
}
```

and here's the method:

```
- (void)pushViewController:(NSString *)user andProfilePicture:(FBProfilePictureView *)profilePicture
{
    NeXtViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NeXt"];
    controller.FBNameString = user;
    //controller.profilePicture.profileID = profilePicture.profileID;
    [controller setFBProfilePicture:profilePicture];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:NO];
}
```

Is there anything im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "not able to send the FBProfilePicture though here is the method"?

Comment: im not able to pass the facebook pic to profileViewController

Comment: after logging in, loginViewController

Comment: If you got Url String in Profilrpicture then you should search for load image from server.

Comment: we url i did it without one with the user.name so it should be possible to do it like that with ProfilePictureView

Comment: how to use the url is it the only way

Answer (score 0):

It seems that firstly you need initialize object and only then set property for it:

```
FBProfilePicture = [[FBProfilePictureClass alloc] init];
FBProfilePicture.profileID = user.id;
```

Comment: and where do i place this in the profileViewCOntroller viewDidLoad;

Comment: or in the loginViewController because i init the object when i made an IBOutlet with using the UIView and changed the class to FBProfilePictureView

Comment: you could place it in `- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user` before pushing profile view controller.